# Click button on the website (Google) in C# using WebClient class

Tags: c#, webclient

Welcome back, again, I have a problem with downloading data from the Internet. Namely, I want to click through the program of the "I'm Feeling Lucky" on Google (in any way for evil :P). The best way, so probably will download ID button and calling the onClick (). I found about weight issues, but in any case the questioner did not use "pure" C#, but use the WebBrowser class, which I think in a regular C# to use is impossible. I would like to put, using the WebClient class (if possible).

Thanks in advance.

PS. If, however, the topic was, then I apologize, I did not find, and if you could, I would appreciate a link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this will help, here's the felling lucky link format:

http://www.google.com/search?q=evil&btnI

Make your WebBrowser point to this URL and you are done

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can handle it.